# Replace "^=^" with "=" where result remains text

Tags: excel, vba, replace

I inherited this sheet in which all of a sudden this piece is not working. It doesn't throw any errors, just nothing happens

```vb
CreatorWB.Sheets(TabNames(i, 1)).Cells.Replace What:="^=^", _ 
  Replacement:="=", LookAt:= _
  xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
  ReplaceFormat:=False
```

As soon as "^=^" changes to "=", the text changes to formulas.

If I do a search and replace outside of VBA (with ctrl + H), Excel thinks I'm inadvertently changing a text to formula.

My general intuition is that if it isn't possible in the interface, it isn't possible in code. It surprises me that this worked before.

Comment: What should happen? You don't want text to change to formula when the `Replace` is performed?  Doing it manually changes text to formula as well for me in XL2010.

Comment: Has anything changed in the TabNames array? is it possible that it is not storing the Sheet Names correctly? From the looks of it, this seems to be inside a loop, it may not be pulling the Sheet Names correctly if they changed or if other portions of the code changed.

Comment: The sheetname is correct, it just doesn't do anything when that line is executed. I want it to work as formulas as soon as "^" are removed.

Answer (score 0):

I think it stopped working for me because excel thinks I'm trying to make text into a formula unintentionally. I worked around it parsing through cells and making

cells(i,j).formula = "=" & right( Formula_string), len(formula_string,3))

This is not an optimal solution but it solved my problem for now.